# Splitting string and passing to different program acts unexpectedly

Tags: c, split

I have a C program that is meant to split a string and then use the results to execute a different program and pass part of the input as arguments.

When "ex ./PATH ARGS" is entered it is supposed to execute the program at PATH and pass ARGS as an array of arguments.

I am testing this with a program that prints out the arguments that are passed to it. Sometimes this works fine but sometimes it shows unexpected behaviour such as printing nothing or printing extra newlines

This code splits the string by spaces

```
 //get rid of the newline character
        input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';
        char** split = g_strsplit(input, " ", NULL);

        //get rid of extra spaces
        GPtrArray* splitArray = g_ptr_array_new();
        int i = 0;
        while(split[i] != NULL){
            if(strcmp(split[i], " ") != 0){
                g_ptr_array_add(splitArray, split[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }
```

This checks the input and calls the function to start a new process if applicable

```
if(strcmp(g_ptr_array_index(splitArray, 0), "ex") == 0){
        //grab first and second index
        char* index1 = g_ptr_array_index(splitArray, 1);

        if(index1 != NULL){
            if(!createProcess(index1, (char**)&splitArray->pdata[1])){
                exit(-1);
            }
        }else{
            fprintf(stderr, "A file must be specified\n");
        }
    }
```

This then frees the memory at the end of each loop iteration

```
g_ptr_array_free(splitArray, true);
    for(int i = 0; i <= numTokens; i++){
        free(split[i]);
    }
    free(split);
```

This is the function that starts a new process

```
bool createProcess(char* file, char** args) {
pid_t pid;

pid = fork();

if (pid < 0) {
    printf("Fork failed");
    return false;
} else if (pid == 0) {
    execvp(file, args);
} else {
    wait(NULL);
}
return true;
```

}

This is the program I am using to test

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `\0` is **not** the newline character!!!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know, that is meant to be replacing the newline character at the end of the string with a null termination character

Comment: hm, so you know there's a newline character at the end of the string?

Comment: Yeah, i use getline to capture user input. The getine function captures the newline used to submit input